# Google AreaChart and date axis is having a wrong Date

Tags: javascript, json, date, google-visualization

I'm facing a problem that I'm not sure how to deal with. I'm creating a Google Area Chart using a json response from a server. I'm using date type columns.

Here is the json data that I'm getting from the server (copy/paste). It is order by date:

```
{
    "cols": [
        {"id":"1", "label":"Dates", "pattern":"", "type":"date"},
        {"id":"2", "label":"Rate", "pattern":"", "type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,01,23)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,01,24)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,01,26)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,06)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,09)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,11)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,15)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,17)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,19)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,27)"},
                {"v":4}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,28)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,02)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,03)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,09)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,13)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,14)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,17)"},
                {"v":5}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,21)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,28)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,29)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,01)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,03)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,05)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,29)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,30)"},
                {"v":4}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The cannot see anything wrong with this data, but the final graph looks like:

[image]

It's seems that Date(2016,1,23) and all dates  corresponding to February are transformed to March.

Even more weird, if I shift by one month all the dates like so:

```
{
    "cols": [
        {"id":"1", "label":"Dates", "pattern":"", "type":"date"},
        {"id":"2", "label":"Rate", "pattern":"", "type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,23)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,24)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,02,26)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,06)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,09)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,11)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,15)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,17)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,19)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,27)"},
                {"v":4}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,03,28)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,02)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,03)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,09)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,13)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,14)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,17)"},
                {"v":5}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,21)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,28)"},
                {"v":2}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,04,29)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,05,01)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,05,03)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,05,05)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,05,29)"},
                {"v":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {"v":"Date(2016,05,30)"},
                {"v":4}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the expected behavior
[image]

Any ideas of what could be happening? The order seems to be fine for me... I tried different browsers and I'm still getting the same result. Also this happening if is use LineChart instead of AreaCharts

**EDIT**

I found out that the problem is not the graph itself but the parsing of the json response.

I'm using angularjs, when I console.log the server response I see that  all the Date values are automatically parsed but with a wrong month.

I solved this in a not very elegant way by doing the following:

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url_to_server,
            transformResponse: [function (data) {
            return data; \\ just to really get the unparsed response
        }]
        }).success(function (data) {

            data = JSON.parse(data,dateTimeReviver);


        });
```

where dateTimeReviver is defined as

```
var dateTimeReviver = function (key, value) {

if (typeof value === 'string') {

    if(value.indexOf('Date(') > -1){

        return eval(value);

    }

}
return value;
```

}

Of course I had to changed the server response to "new Date(2016,01,23)" format. As I said it is not elegant/optimal, if somebody has any suggestions please, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

is there more you can share, what options do you set?
seems to work fine here, added point size for visibility

`Date(2016,01,23)` appears correctly...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
        "cols": [
            {"id":"1", "label":"Dates", "pattern":"", "type":"date"},
            {"id":"2", "label":"Rate", "pattern":"", "type":"number"}
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,01,23)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,01,24)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,01,26)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,06)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,09)"},
                    {"v":2}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,11)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,15)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,17)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,19)"},
                    {"v":2}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,27)"},
                    {"v":4}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,02,28)"},
                    {"v":2}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,02)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,03)"},
                    {"v":2}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,09)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,13)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,14)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,17)"},
                    {"v":5}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,21)"},
                    {"v":2}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,28)"},
                    {"v":2}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,03,29)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,04,01)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,04,03)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,04,05)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,04,29)"},
                    {"v":1}
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {"v":"Date(2016,04,30)"},
                    {"v":4}
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, {pointSize: 5});
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I tested it as well and it is working. The problem it is related with the Json parsing when I get the values from the server. Somehow the Date string is parsed in the wrong way. I'll detail this in another answer

Comment: i'm thinking `jsapi` has the JSON parse issue, here is another [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37531340/5090771), corrected by using `loader.js`

Comment: Not sure that's the problem in my case, since if I console.log the data right after getting it from the server, already shows the problem. I could try in any case :)