# Goole Visualization DateRangeFilter Data issue. Data Conflict between Feb and March

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When I'm selecting the dates between 1st feb to 28th feb, the Google visualization displaying the data of March instead of February.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cihuy.png)

The Below code has data and control and chart wrappers.

```
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart','controls','table'], callback:drawChart});
```

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/d35k7oxw/1/)

Please help me in finding a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the newer library, `loader.js` vs `jsapi`

seems to work fine here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date','OrderDate');
    data.addColumn('number','Order_Qty');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2014,0,1),100],
      [new Date(2014,0,3),120],
      [new Date(2014,0,30),110],
      [new Date(2014,1,1),170],
      [new Date(2014,1,10),180],
      [new Date(2014,1,25),110],
      [new Date(2014,2,1),170],
      [new Date(2014,2,14),170],
      [new Date(2014,2,20),170],
      [new Date(2014,3,12),170],
      [new Date(2014,3,16),170],
      [new Date(2014,3,13),170]
    ]);


    var table_Chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Table',
      'containerId': 'table_div',
      'options': {},
      'view': {'columns':[0, 1]}
    });

    var slider_Date = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'filter_date_div_Date',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnIndex':'0'
        }
    });

    new  google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'))
    .bind([slider_Date],[table_Chart])
    .draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="filter_date_div_Date"></div>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Google charts Date() handling. It is fixed now by its developer.

Github: **google/google-visualization-issues** [Chart data series shows up mis-aligned for all February data](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2275#issuecomment-222537641)

Answer (score 0):

Short term solution for the .clone() and .toDataTable() issue with the live version of the Visualization.

**Clone Usage:**

prev: newDatatable = oldDatatable.clone();

now: newDatatable = cloneDataTable(oldDatatable);

**ToDatatableUsage:**

prev: newDatatable = oldDataView.toDatatable();

now: newDatatable = convertDataViewToDataTable(oldDataView);

**Functions:**

```
function cloneDataTable(dataTable) {
    var newDataTable = dataTable.clone();
    for (var c = 0; c < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
        if (dataTable.getColumnType(c) == 'datetime' || dataTable.getColumnType(c) == 'date' ) {
            for (var r = 0; r < dataTable.getNumberOfRows() ; r++) {
                newDataTable.setValue(r, c, dataTable.getValue(r, c));
            }
        }
    }
    return newDataTable;
}

function convertDataViewToDataTable(dataView) {
    var newDataTable = dataView.toDataTable();
    for (var c = 0; c < dataView.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
        if (dataView.getColumnType(c) == 'datetime' || dataView.getColumnType(c) == 'date' ) {
            for (var r = 0; r < dataView.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
                newDataTable.setValue(r, c, dataView.getValue(r, c));
            }
        }
    }
    return newDataTable;
}
```

Hope this helps...
J